# Android - Timer for intervals

Tags: android, timer

For some time I can't figure out what is the problem, and I don't know anymore where to look for the answer, so I'm asking you guys. I want to create timer for intervals with user data input (time of training, time of break, number of repetitions). And I would like it to work like that:
There are 2 text view which are showing: timer for Training time, timer for Break time)
First one running is training time until it will be egual to time of training input data.
Then time of break is running.
All of this working in for loop (until number of repetitions will be finished).
But when I'm pushing start button it freezes. Graddle showed no errors.

Edit:
I figure out that it is the problem with while loop (I have three of them). But this while loop is in runnable already and should work. Should I create new Runnable and make it like a Thread? I tried this, but still it's not working. I don't know how could I make it working.

Here is my code:

```
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Handler;


public class Interval extends AppCompatActivity {
  private TextView timerValue;
  private TextView timerValue2;
  private TextView repetition;
  private long startTime = 0L;
  private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
  long timeV, timeB, train, tbreak;
  long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
  long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
  long updatedTime = 0L;
  int reps;
  Button resetButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_interval);
    train = getIntent().getLongExtra("train", 0);
    tbreak = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("tbreak", 0);
   reps = getIntent().getIntExtra("reps", 0);
    resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    resetButton.setEnabled(false);
    timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    timerValue2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    repetition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    repetition.setText("0/" + reps);


}

public void startButton(View view) {
    startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
    resetButton.setEnabled(false);

}

public void pauseButton(View view) {
    timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
    customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
    resetButton.setEnabled(true);

}

public void resetButton(View view) {
}
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
        for (int x=1; x<reps; x++) {
            long y = (long)x;
            repetition.setText("" + x + "/" + reps);
            timerValue.setText("0:00:000");
            timerValue2.setText("0:00:000");
            timeV = updatedTime - (y - 1) * (train + tbreak);
            while (timeV <= train) {
                int secs = (int) (timeV / 1000);
                int mins = secs / 60;
                secs = secs % 60;
                int milliseconds = (int) (timeV % 1000);
                timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                        + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                        + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            }
            while (train < timeV && timeV <= (train + tbreak)) {
                timerValue.setText("0:00:000");
                timeB = timeV - train;
                int secs = (int) (timeB / 1000);
                int mins = secs / 60;
                secs = secs % 60;
                int milliseconds = (int) (timeB % 1000);
                timerValue2.setText("" + mins + ":"
                        + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                        + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            }
            if (x==reps-1){
                timeV = updatedTime - y * (train + tbreak);
                while (timeV <= train) {
                    int secs = (int) (timeV / 1000);
                    int mins = secs / 60;
                    secs = secs % 60;
                    int milliseconds = (int) (timeV % 1000);
                    timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                            + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                            + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
                }
            }
        }

        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }
};
```

}